# excel find row based on current day

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am new to excel macros

I am trying to create a simple macro which based on the current day (as I am asking this question today is Friday), find "Friday" in any row and then copy all these rows to a new sheet, I have reached this point, Any help is appreciated.

```
With ActiveSheet
With Range(“A1”, Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
.AutoFilter 1, “Friday”
On Error Resume Next
End With
End With
```

Comment: AutoFilter won't help you here. Are you familiar with the concept of a For loop? You'll need to step through each line on the spreadsheet and check to see if it contains your search value ("Friday").

Comment: I am not sure about which part you need assistance with but `Format(Now, "dddd")` can generate string Friday if that is your aim.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij what I want is to copy all rows containing today's date to a new sheet

Comment: Day (today is Friday) and Date (today is 29-May-20) are two different things, you are mixing them up. In your example you are showing day. Do you need help with the code that checks each cell? Is your data in one column or it can be anywhere?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij it can be anywhere, yes the text I am looking to find is friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below logic to work this out. You need to write appropriate logic to copy the data as per your needs in the commented line.

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lngLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    lngLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    For i = 1 To lngLastRow
        For j = 1 To lngLastCol
            If .Cells(i, j).Value = Format(Now, "dddd") Then
                '\\ Write Cell / Row Copying Code Here
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: this is great, is there a way to make the "Friday" dynamic i.e tomorrow will be saturday...

Comment: @User19 please see my first comment on your question and edit above.